# change MySQL commands to PostgreSQL in a bash script

Tags: mysql, pg-dump

I have a bash script to backup MySQL databases. I have pasted the relevant part below (ignore the variables).

The 2 lines I think I need to change to make this work in PostgreSQL are;

`DBS="$(mysql --login-path=dbbkup -Bse 'show databases')"`

and

`$MYSQLDUMP --login-path=dbbkup --add-drop-database --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --set-gtid-purged=OFF $db | $GZIP > $FILE`

Can anyone advise as to how I can get the same functionality with PostgreSQL?

```
# get all database listing
DBS="$(mysql --login-path=dbbkup -Bse 'show databases')"

# start to dump database one by one
for db in $DBS
do
        DUMP="yes";
        if [ "$IGNOREDB" != "" ]; then
                for i in $IGNOREDB # Store all value of $IGNOREDB ON i
                do
                        if [ "$db" == "$i" ]; then # If result of $DBS(db) is equal to $IGNOREDB(i) then
                                DUMP="NO";         # SET value of DUMP to "no"
                                #echo "$i database is being ignored!";
                        fi
                done
        fi

        if [ "$DUMP" == "yes" ]; then # If value of DUMP is "yes" then backup database
                FILE="$BACKUPDIR/$NOW-$db.sql.gz";
                echo "BACKING UP $db";
        $MYSQLDUMP --login-path=dbbkup --add-drop-database --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --set-gtid-purged=OFF $db | $GZIP > $FILE
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've cracked it...with a LOT of Googling and chopping of code!

`DBS="$(sudo -u postgres psql -l -t | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed -e 's/ //g' -e '/^$/d')"`

and;

`sudo -u postgres $PGDUMP -Fc --verbose $db | $GZIP > $FILE`

```
# get all database listing
DBS="$(sudo -u postgres psql -l -t | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed -e 's/ //g' -e '/^$/d')"

# start to dump database one by one
for db in $DBS
do
        DUMP="yes";
        if [ "$IGNOREDB" != "" ]; then
                for i in $IGNOREDB # Store all value of $IGNOREDB ON i
                do
                        if [ "$db" == "$i" ]; then # If result of $DBS(db) is equal to $IGNOREDB(i) then
                                DUMP="NO";         # SET value of DUMP to "no"
                                #echo "$i database is being ignored!";
                        fi
                done
        fi

        if [ "$DUMP" == "yes" ]; then # If value of DUMP is "yes" then backup database
                FILE="$BACKUPDIR/$NOW-$db.sql.gz";
                 echo "BACKING UP $db";
                      sudo -u postgres $PGDUMP -Fc --verbose $db | $GZIP > $FILE
        fi
done
```